# Why won't Section frame resize to show list content

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a Section that runs a ForEach to return header: and then another view returns a fetchRequest for the Content. The problem is the content size of the section is only 1 row height of the fetchRequest high. If I apply the modifier of `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` the size doesn't change. If I apply `.frame(maxHeight: 200` it does get bigger.

Why doesn't .infinity dynamically increase the height

```
    List{
           
            ForEach(books, id: \.self) { thisbook in
                Section(header:
                            HStack {
                           Text(thisbook.number ?? "number string error")
                            Text(thisbook.wrappedFirstname)
                            Text(thisbook.lastName ?? "Last Name string error")
                            Text(thisbook.to ?? "To string error")
                            Text(thisbook.from ?? "From string error")
                            })
                {
                    BookList(filterKey: "number", filterValue: thisbook.wrappednumber){(books: Books) in
                    Text("\(books.wrappedBooks)")
                    }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                }
                }
```

Comment: Use fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical : true)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text in SwiftUI Form not wrapping after being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676540/text-in-swiftui-form-not-wrapping-after-being-changed)

Comment: If I add the .fixedSize it doesn't show the BookList view at all.